With 4.2 EEVEE, how do I get high-emission parts of the background HDRI to render to the emit layer?
I'm using 4.2 EEVEE (no bloom) and I'm trying to make stars in the background HDRI flicker by mixing low-emission and high-emission shaders driven by evolving noise, then in the compositor running the emit layer through a glare node, but the background stars are not showing up on the emit layer at all. Is this a bug of some kind? How do I get high-emission parts of the background HDRI to show up on my emission layer?
I've been following this 2.8 tutorial mostly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErMY5wq7bjM

I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished, under development or experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. These transitory questions are unlikely to be useful in the future, rendering their long term value low, and making them unappealing for a knowledge database site.

Hello can you revise your question to stick to stable released Blender versions. The latest is 4.1.1. Else your question may be off-topic.

You should probably share your blend file for this, but best I can tell from your description this should be working, so you must’ve done something wrong. Considering the tutorial is fairly out of date, it’s probably unreliable.

As far as I know, there's no bloom planned for the stable release of 4.2, so the question will remain relevant. I tried switching to 4.1, but I'm using some features of the 4.2 EEVEE, which make the scene look like crap in 4.1. And no, it shouldn't be working as bloom was removed from the latest EEVEE. I did find a workaround: using a ramped mist layer as a mask to run a separate glare pass on the sky and compositing that back in.
